# Syntax errors creating a stored procedure

Tags: mysql

```
Create procedure Movestaff (input_staffID smallINT, new_deptID tinyINT)
BEGIN
 declare old_deptID tinyINT;
 start transaction;
 select departmentID into old_deptID from staff where staffID=input_staffID;
 update staff set departmentID = new_deptID where staffID=input_staffID;
 update department set staffCount = staffCount-1 where departmentID =old_deptID;
 update department set staffCount = staffCount+1 where departmentID =new_deptID;
 Commit;
END
```

My teacher at uni provided us with this stored procedure to analyse and evaluate, except it doesn't work when trying to execute it. It's too late now to receive a reply (5pm). We only started this content recently. I'm receiving a generic MySQL error on line 3 - declare old_deptID.

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: Line 3  - so right where the delimiter occurs

Answer (score 2):

A common problem with stored procedures is that the delimiter normally used by the language  ( a ';') to indicate the end of a statement.  Of course with stored procedures, there may be several statements inside one large block of code - as in your example.
The way round this is to change the delimiter:

```
delimiter $$
```

So now it will execute everything until the next $$ as one piece of code.  So do this prior to running your statement.  Then run your code **with** a $$ at the end.
Don't forget to change it back after with

```
delimiter ;
```